# Is harsh made from the word hard?

Tags: etymology

I had a test today an I was asked to complete “.... criminal” with a word formation for “hard”, I did it with the word “harsh”, is it correct?

Comment: I think they were looking for "hardened"—an idiomatic usage meaning "lacking in sympathy, pity, remorse, restraint, human kindness, etc."

Comment: I like to see more of such creative questions. See also my comments below.

Comment: @SvenYargs +1 True, but *hardened* need not always be negative. It has come to mean "incorrigible" only in some collocations like this. Cf. *battle-hardened* etc.

Answer (score 1):

The etymonline entries indicate that [hard](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hard) and [harsh](https://www.etymonline.com/word/harsh) come from different root words.

It's more likely that the test was looking for the term *hardened criminal*.

> **hardened** *adjective*
>   2.1 Utterly fixed in a habit or way of life seen as bad.
>   ‘hardened criminals’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/hardened)

Comment: It is not about the correct answer to the test question but the relation, if any, between *hard* and *harsh* as your first sentence talks about.

Comment: @Kris I answered the question, then provided some useful information.